# ImageIcon cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, eclipse, jlabel, imageicon, windowsbuilder

I wrote the following code:

```
JLabel lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel("");
Image img= new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/timeplanner11.jpg")).getImage();
lblNewLabel_1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));
lblNewLabel_1.setBounds(0, 0, 28, 30);
panel.add(lblNewLabel_1);
```

It is showing the error:

```
ImageIcon cannot be resolved to a type
```

Can someone please help me in correcting this error?

Thank you!!!

Comment: Import the class?

Comment: Why create an `ImageIcon`, only to get the `Image` to then wrap it in another `ImageIcon`??

Comment: What would be the better approach?

Comment: check the answer

Answer (score 2):

Add an import for javax.swing.ImageIcon at the top of your class or add `javax.swing.` before every call to `ImageIcon` like so:

```
javax.swing.ImageIcon icon = new javax.swing.ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/timeplanner11.jpg"));
lblNewLabel_1.setIcon(icon);
```

Also as suggested by @MadProgrammer just keep it as an ImageIcon, there is no need to create an Image, just do it like this:

```
JLabel lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel("");
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/timeplanner11.jpg"));
lblNewLabel_1.setIcon(icon);
lblNewLabel_1.setBounds(0, 0, 28, 30);
panel.add(lblNewLabel_1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `Image` with `ImageIcon`

```
ImageIcon img= new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/timeplanner11.jpg")).getImage();
```